# Remove empty titles in wordpress sidebar widgets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have registered a wordpress sidebar like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'First Sidebar', 'theme_name' ),
    'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'theme_name' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

The problem is that when the title is empty, the **h3**'s still get rendered. Is there a way to remove these when the title is left blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing the `before_title` and `after_title` is something that is done in the function `widget( $args, $instance )` by the widget self. All of the default wordpress 3.1 widgets check if the title is empty before parsing `before_title` and `after_title`, but I guess you're using a custom widget from a theme or plugin, in that case you'll have to adjust the `widget( $args, $instance )` code.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a small addition to Mark's answer. The default calendar widget uses `&nbsp;` if the title is empty, so it still displays an empty header. I worked round that by adding this to my theme's `functions.php`:

```
function foo_widget_title($title)
{
    return $title == '&nbsp;' ? '' : $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title', foo_widget_title);
```

Changing 'foo' to something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to thank Daniel James for his snippet - this is beautiful. I made a small change where I replaced   with !no_display, then added !no_display to the title of my widgets in the front-end. This made it clear to my users that it was a hook to be referenced in a function (and not to be confused with a seemingly empty widget title).

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template and check for the existence of a title. If no title is set do not print the h3.

Answer (score 0):

Register two sidebars, identical but for the `'before_title'` and `'after_title'` values. Check for a title, and then call one or the other accordingly.